# Is it possible to write a css rule and then ask some elements to ignore it?

Tags: css

I want to have all images take this rule

```
img{width:300px;height:300px;}
```

except for a couple of images which I want to keep their default ratio. How can this be accomplished? I know it's not best practice but due to certain project limitations this may be the only way I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.default-image
{
  width: auto; 
  height: auto;
}

<!-- Image with default bounds -->
<img src="..." class="default-image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

A more specific selector will override a less specific selector.  So if you have

```
img{width:300px;height:300px;}
```

and also

```
img.keepMySize{width:auto;height:auto;}
```

then an image with the keepMySize class will not be affected by the sizes you assigned to img in general.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 6.6.7. The negation pseudo-class http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

> Examples: The following selector
>   matches all button elements in an HTML
>   document that are not disabled.
>   button:not([DISABLED])

```
img:not(.thisimage) {...}
```

[Compatibility](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-not)